# camel test sftp copy files

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

We're using camel (2.6)  to copy some file from a route to another one. Since we don't have unit test I'm trying to write a new one, but I'm getting all the time this error:

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: sftp://admin@localhost/?connectTimeout=1800000&delay=1800000&disconnect=true&filter=%23myFileFilter&initialDelay=120000&passiveMode=true&password=admin&reconnectDelay=180000&recursive=true&useFixedDelay=true due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFileFilter
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:449)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:463)
```

I paste my code:

```
<bean id="myFileFilter" class="com.my.test.RouteFileFilter">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"
        value="Regex_filter"/>
</bean>
```

RouteFilter is an implementation of the genericFileFilter

then, in the unit test I'm doing this:

```
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
Exchange ex = new DefaultExchange(ctx);
Endpoint endpoint = new SftpEndpoint(sourceURI, new SftpComponent(), new SftpConfiguration());
ctx.addEndpoint(sourceURI, endpoint);

ctx.addRoutes(myBuilder);
ctx.start();
```

this is the line where I get the error:

```
getContext().getEndpoint(getSourceURIWithFilter(), GenericFileEndpoint.class).setProcessStrategy(new DefaultRouteFileProcessStrategy(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I found a lot of these errors on the web and no one that can answer to this. 
Here the solution:

```
mMyBuilder mybuilder  = new MyBuilder();
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
registry.put("myFileFilter", myfileFilter); // myFileFilter is an instance of your filter
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);

myBuilder.setMyFilter("#myFilter");
// your code
context.addRoutes(myBuilder);
context.start();
```